# I wanted to show an XML tag <Cat_Desc> in a web View but it is having HTML tags also

Tags: android, html-parsing, xml-parsing, android-webview

I have to parse data from xml.this is my xml- or its url is:   http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml

```
  <Cat_Name>News for the day</Cat_Name>
    <Cat_Desc>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: medium; "><img src="http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/assetmanager/images/gns_header.jpg" alt="" align="middle" border="1px" height="90" width="550"></span></div><span class="Apple-style-span" style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; "><br><div style="text-align: center;">Yes we are coming at E & I? Are you?</div></span><br><h1 style="font-weight: bold; "><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; ">News for the day...</span></h1><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); "><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; ">Template Mobile Sites for IC: <a href="http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/">http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/</a></span><br><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Promotional valid till 30 Sept 2011: MOBILE WEBSITE (Base Product Mobile CMS) for JUST $159<br></span></span><br><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Mobile Template link: </span><a href="http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/"><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/</span><br></a><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; "><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">With the promotion on Business Edge and eFusion still running successful in e market place - $ 499</span><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); ">Check out some of the latest site launch on: </span><br><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; ">http://www.randallcontracting.co.uk/Pages/Default.aspx </span><br><br><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-size: 10pt; "><span style="font-weight: bold; ">Category</span>: Building & Construction</span><br></span><br></span><div style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); text-align: left; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; ">Description: WELCOME TO RANDALL CONTRACTING Randall Contracting is a family-run contracting SME which has been servicing London and the South East since 1956. Working closely with our Clients and external Design Consultants, we place great emphasis on a safe, positive, practical and common sense approach to our projects. Our delivery methods have resulted in an extensive volume of repeat business from both Private and Public Sectors. Safety and Environmental concerns are a high priority on all our contracts and we continually strive to source innovative working methods and solutions. Our equipment is regularly updated and maintained to ensure minimal environmental impact.</span><br><br></div><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; "><br></span></span><br>
        </Cat_Desc>
```

i added one snap for first cat_name.Any way to uploaded whole cat_description in webview or any other view in android or i need to parse one by one and display one by one.

[image]

this image has  tag data

any help would be appreciated.Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Guys i got the Answer that is , we just have to save to the **whole XML (with HTML tags)** in an **String** and then pass that string to the WebView. It will show all your data. Its is because **WebViews Understands only HTML or XML** so when we pass them our HTML string in XML format.. It Understands and display our content as its is we wanted.